# Binding variables to SQLAlchemy query for Pandas.read_sql

Tags: python, pandas, oracle11g, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

Is it possible to bind variables to a SQLAlchemy query used in a Pandas.read_sql statement?

Using %s in the WHERE clause does not work and the documentation for cx_Oracle states:

> cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department_id=:dept_id)

Using the cx_Oracle driver directly is deprecated in Pandas and is not a viable option.

I have a list of groups I need to iterate through the WHERE statement as SELECT * is too large in memory to handle on a single PC.

**EXAMPLE:**

`SELECT *
 FROM DUAL
 WHERE GROUP_NAME = %s`

Returns this error:

> (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00911: invalid character **...** WHERE GROUP_NAME = %s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.paramstyle), `cx_Oracle.paramstyle` is `named` not `format`. According to [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) you have to use the `:name` syntax for `named` `paramstyle`:

```
import pandas as pd
sql = '''
 SELECT *
 FROM DUAL
 WHERE GROUP_NAME = :name
'''
df = pd.read_sql(sql, params={'name': the_name_you_want})
```

---

Comment: what is the syntax for passing in a list of values for the parameter, instead of just one?