# How to save sql table as pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, cx-oracle

I have been trying to extracting a sql table using cx_oracle and saving it as pandas dataframe using the following script:

```
import  cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

id = 1234
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password='pwd',dsn="dsn")
# Obtain a cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()
# Execute the query
query = """select * from table where id= {id}"""
my_sql =cursor.execute(query.format(id=id))
df_sql = pd.read_sql(my_sql, connection)
```

I am able to connect to the database but I am unable to save it as pandas dataframe. How do I do that? I get the following error :

```
  File "file/to/path.py", line 38, in file
    df_sql = pd.read_sql(my_sql, connection)
  File "C:\file/to/path\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 495, in read_sql
    return pandas_sql.read_query(
  File "File/to/path\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1771, in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
  File "File/to/path\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1737, in execute
    raise ex from exc
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '<cx_Oracle.Cursor on <cx_Oracle.Connection to dsn>>': expecting string or bytes object
```

Comment: can you post the full stack trace? looks like a connection/query issue.

Comment: Updated the error message

Comment: I have added it as an aswer (please comment in the answer, which one you used and which one worked)

Comment: Do not do `query = """select * from table where id= {id}"""` since this opens you to SQL injection security attacks and also affects performance and scalability.  Use a bind variable, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51790579/4799035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to the `pd.read_sql` should be the query (if I'm not mistaken). You are parsing a `cursor` object. Try replace `my_sql` in `pd.read_sql` with `query` i.e

`pd.read_sql(query.format(id=id))`

or use the cursor object i.e

`df = pd.DataFrame(my_sql.fetchall())`

Note, `fetchall()` does only return the data i.e not the header, which can be obtained using `cursor.description` (see the SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010042/mysql-get-column-name-or-alias-from-query) )

Comment: I used ```pd.read_sql(query.format(id=id))``` and it worked! Thanks for the help